# Creating users in subversion?

Tags: security, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

How I can create users in Subversion.

For when people access the repository, only to see their projects or files and not those of the other people?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer depends on how Subversion server is setup.

- If you're using httpd then it depends on how authentication is setup in httpd. See [SVNBook | Authentication options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn).
- If you're using svnserve then you can use [the built in authentication setup](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth).
- And if you're using `svn+ssh://` then either users log into ssh as their own user (in which case how to add users is a function of adding users to ssh) or they log into as a shared user and [the `--tunnel-user` argument gets set](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks.fixedcmd).